# Storing lots of small files: archive vs. filesystem

Tags: java, performance, caching, storage

I am creating an application that requires a lot of image thumbnails (~3000, 5-25KB). Because speed is essential I plan on loading these images into memory when the application starts. At runtime, new thumbnails will be downloaded and added to the collective.

I could store them all in a folder, but reading thousands of files into memory when a program starts hardly seems efficient.

My second option would be to save them in some kind of (compressed) archive. This would make storage itself and loading more efficient (I think). However, new files will be added regularly, and that will probably not go as smoothly as just saving them in a folder.

Is storing a cache of small files in a (compressed) archive a bad idea or not? Are ZIP files the way to go? Would I be better off using uncompressed archives (and if so, what kind)?

All image files will be JPEG's.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I am considering to drop the "load everything into memory on application start" thing. This would simplify my question a little. My initial idea to put everything in one big file now seems less beneficial, since the problem of many files in one directory can be solved by hashing into subdirectories.

Comment: compression works very poorly on compressed image file formats (png jpg gif) -- image formats are already compressed better than a general purpose compression algorithm can manage.  You'd probably be just as well off with a `.tar` -- lower overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small files don't compress especially well, so you may not gain much compression.

While loading the files will be fast because they are smaller, decompression adds time. You'd have to experiment to see which is faster.

I would think the real issues would relate to the efficiency of the file system when it comes to iterating over all the little files, especially if they are all in one folder. Windows is notorious for being pretty inefficient when folders contain lots of files.

I would consider doing something like writing them out into one file, uncompressed, that could be streamed into memory -- maybe not necessarily contiguous memory, as that might be a problem. But the idea would be to put them all in one file. Then write some kind of index that ties a file name or other identifier to an offset from which the location of the image in memory could be determined.

New images could be added at the end, and the index updated appropriately.

It isn't fancy but that's what you're trying to avoid. An archive or even a file system gives you lots of power and flexibility but at the cost of efficiency. When you know what you want to do, sometimes simple is better.

I would consider implementing a solution that reads files from a folder, another that divides the files into subfolders and subsubfolders so there are no more than 100 or so files in any given folder, then time those solutions so you have something to compare to. I would think a simple indexed file would be fast enough that you wouldn't even need to pre-load the images like you're suggesting -- just retrieve them as you need them and keep them around once they're in memory.

Comment: That's exactly the kind of container storage I had in mind! Now that I've decided against loading everything into memory at program start, it's down to the following choice: one big indexed file, or saving the images in hash-distributed subfolders. Separate files seems simpler to implement, but I'm willing to benchmark both options. Do you know of any Java library that supports the uncompressed archive you're describing? Or is this something I will have to create myself?

Comment: An uncompressed archive ===> you may use a ZipOutputStream which does not compress data

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html

Comment: invoke setMethod() on the stream passing ZipOutputStream.STORED instead of ZipOutputStream.DEFLATED, and then write any files to the stream

Comment: Thanks! It didn't occur to me to search for uncompressed storage methods in the zip-section of the API.

Answer (score 1):

All disk based storage, and most database, allocate space in chunks. The chunks on large capacity disks can be large. If you have 5kb files and a 32kb disk chunk you end up with 85% wasted space on your storage.

Using an archive won't compress jpeg much because the jpeg encoding algorithm already does that. It will however save you the wasted space on the storage media. It does make things more complicated and perhaps a little slower.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even think of that! The application will typically run on systems with 4KB block size, and since we're only talking about a few thousand files anyway the file system overhead should be no more than a few megabytes. It's now either simply storing all files on the disk or putting them in an uncompressed container.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion I think that the zip file way it´s a bad idea, because you will slowdown everything with the process to load the zip file and unzip it to extract each image.

I think that the purpose of a thumbnail image is that by nature is small so your app plus hardware can load it as fast as possible. So I believe that it is a better idea to load each image as you need it.

Comment: Yes, you're right, zipping JPEG's does sound rather stupid. I created the thumbnail system because all images in the cache are downloaded from a server. Somehow downloading a few thousand 1 to 5 megabyte files seems like a bad idea. However it may indeed be best if I just load them from the hard drive on the fly.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have small, "geometric" pictures, you may implement them as objects of type javax.swing.Icon rather than images to load from the filesystem.
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Icon.html

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html

So you will implement one or more objects which draw themselves onto a Graphics surface using the Graphics drawing primitives, instead of copying pixels.

Comment: Unfortunately most images are photo-like. That's why I went for JPEG's. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score -1):

If this is a web-application then the best performance boost you can get is setting good HTTP caching headers. Having a unique URL for every image (also different URLs for different versions of the same image) makes it possible to set VERY far future expire headers, because changing the image changes the URL leading into refetch.

I won't compress, because JPEG cannot be good compressed and it only costs CPU time.

I would recommend to simply store the images into filesystem and consider the use of libraries like [jawr](http://jawr.java.net/) or implement your own caching strategy.

Comment: It's not a web-application, sorry, I should have mentioned that. However I didn't know about the existence of jawr. I'm sure it will prove to be useful for me in the future.
Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I know this question has already answered but I think you need more options other than zipping.

While zip is good, It's not really affect much for JPEG since JPEG has already compressed.

Other thing you may want to consider is :

1. Put the image in **Content Delivery Network (CDN)**
2. Compress components with gzip ( mean the server will automatically zip every response ) and you dont need to write any code to unzip it later - it's handled by the browser automatically.
3. Since you mention JPEG, you may want to use **JPEGTran**.Run jpegtran on all your JPEGs.

   This tool does lossless JPEG operations such as rotation and can also be used to optimize and remove comments and other useless information (such as EXIF information) from your images.
   jpegtran -copy none -optimize -perfect src.jpg dest.jpg
4. Use **Image Sprites**. Instead of asking browser to download many image at same time, ask the browser to only download one.

For the details read : http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#opt_images

For the basic examination how to improve your website performance you can try install YSlow ( plugin to detect uneffecient code ) in Firefox.

Hope that helps.